# How to remove all event handlers from an event?

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have the following class

```
Public Class SimpleClass
    Public Event SimpleEvent()

    Public Sub SimpleMethod()
        RaiseEvent SimpleEvent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I instanciate it like

```
    Obj = New SimpleClass

    AddHandler Obj.SimpleEvent, Sub()
                                    MsgBox("Hi !")
                                End Sub
```

And i'm trying to remove the event handler dynamically-created using the code in : [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection)

(I assume a complex application where it's difficult to use : **RemoveHandler Obj.Event, AddressOf Me.EventHandler**)

In their code there is the following method

```
Private Shared Sub BuildEventFields(t As Type, lst As List(Of FieldInfo))
    For Each ei As EventInfo In t.GetEvents(AllBindings)
        Dim dt As Type = ei.DeclaringType
        Dim fi As FieldInfo = dt.GetField(ei.Name, AllBindings)
        If fi IsNot Nothing Then
            lst.Add(fi)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But when calling this code using my object type, the next line returns nothing

```
Dim fi As FieldInfo = dt.GetField(ei.Name, AllBindings)
```

means that somehow my event is not recognized as a field.

Does anyone know how to remove all event handlers from an event ?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the lambda expression that is getting you into trouble here.  Don't dig a deeper hole, just use AddressOf and a private method instead so you can trivially use the RemoveHandler statement.

If you absolutely have to then keep in mind that the VB.NET compiler auto-generates a backing store field for the event with the same name as the event with "Event" appended.  Which makes this code work:

```
    Dim Obj = New SimpleClass
    AddHandler Obj.SimpleEvent, Sub()
                                    MsgBox("Hi !")
                                End Sub

    Dim fi = GetType(SimpleClass).GetField("SimpleEventEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    fi.SetValue(Obj, Nothing)

    Obj.SimpleMethod()      '' No message box
```

I'll reiterate that you should not do this.